# how to use css sprite in all my pages ( menu+ views)

Tags: theming

i have a page contain view and menu and i want to use same icon  for both,
so i made a sprite image but i don't know how to use it in 2 different classes?

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Cheers in advance.

[image: see the image]

Comment: Are you asking how to add a background image with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use same image in different classes already; i am not sure that i understood your problem(I was going to ask for details but my reputation is not enough to add comments yet; so i am adding answer.).

```
.class-one {
  background: url("/your/path/to/images/your-sprite-image.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  ...
}

.class-two {
  background: url("/your/path/to/images/your-sprite-image.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  ...
}
```

If you need to change image's position, you can change first 0 for left, second 0 for top position.

If they are the same; you can merge them:

```
.class-one, .class-two {
  background: url("/your/path/to/images/your-sprite-image.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  ...
}
```